# How to divide circle in grid according to degree?

Tags: python-3.x, plot, geometry, trigonometry

I have 5 types of a entity [1,2,3,4,5] which are in percentages ,let say [10,15,20,25,30] respectively. hence converting in degrees I get [36,54,72,90,108].
First, I am generating my circular-shaped array with binary values in the grid as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from typing import List, Tuple



def collect(x: int, y: int, sigma: float =3.0) -> List[Tuple[int, int]]:
   """ create a small collection of points in a neighborhood of some point 
   """
   neighborhood = []

   X = int(sigma)
   for i in range(-X, X + 1):
       Y = int(pow(sigma * sigma - i * i, 1/2))
       for j in range(-Y, Y + 1):
           neighborhood.append((x + i, y + j))

   return neighborhood


def plotter(sigma: float =3.0) -> None:
   """ Plot a binary grid """    
   arr = np.zeros([sigma * 2 + 1] * 2)

   points = collect(int(sigma), int(sigma), sigma)

   # flip pixel value if it lies inside (or on) the circle
   for p in points:
       arr[p] = 1
   print(arr)
plotter(10)
```

I have grid as [image: Grid]

1. How can I plot the above-generated array as a grid where each element will assign to a unit square which will have a unit dimension? (Intention is not to plot but able to made calculations)
2. How can I maintain the center element with (0,0) like the origin and all other elements like in the four quadrants of the graph?
3. I should be able to get the center point of each element and it's distance from center.
4. I should also able to calculate distance of center to that element on y_axis and x_axis. so using that i should able to get it's angle from origin.

```
theta = math.atan(y_axis_distance_of_ele/x_axis_distance_of_ele)
```

5. Given that I have calculated the angles of every element. If the angle of any element is between 0 to 36-degree, assign the value of ele as 1; for 37 to 90 degrees, assign 2,...; for 253 to 360, assign 5. (Degree value are according to cumulative percentage of assigned degree above)

Desired result: I should be able to divide elements in a circular grid into five different parts according to the percentage of each part, which should look like a pie chart. [Final result can be visualised as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sEH6.jpg), this I just tried to sketch but any approximate result will work for me.

I request you all to suggest logic or python code to do the same. I will be grateful of you, Thank you!

Comment: in the imports, you have `matplotlib`, but have not used it.  the same for `ellipse`, `argparse` and `sqrt`.... so why are they there ?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yeah, you are right, actually initially I was trying to plot it but now I am not focused no it.

Comment: Is it necessary that you want to answer according to to mention logic?

Comment: I mention my logic just to get you an idea of what I was thinking about, but any solution that will lead to the desired result will work for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

it seems as though you are basically there.

all you need to do it to ammend the 1's to different numbers according to whatever rules you like. The only additional part that i reall did was to `return the array from the plotter function` and work with this in `matplotlib`.

then you just have to run matplotlib on the resulting array like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from typing import List, Tuple



def collect(x: int, y: int, sigma: float =3.0) -> List[Tuple[int, int]]:
   """ create a small collection of points in a neighborhood of some point 
   """
   neighborhood = []

   X = int(sigma)
   for i in range(-X, X + 1):
       Y = int(pow(sigma * sigma - i * i, 1/2))
       for j in range(-Y, Y + 1):
           neighborhood.append((x + i, y + j))

   return neighborhood


def plotter(sigma: float =3.0) -> None:
   """ Plot a binary image """    
   arr = np.zeros([sigma * 2 + 1] * 2)

   points = collect(int(sigma), int(sigma), sigma)

   # flip pixel value if it lies inside (or on) the circle
   for p in points:
       arr[p] = 1
    # print(arr)
   return arr
x = plotter(10)

# example of different colours (apply your rules here)
x[5,5] = 5
x[7,7] = -2

# plot the chart
plt.imshow(x)
plt.show()
```

This returns the circle:

[image]

When the 1's are ammended to different values, the colours will appear automatically.

note: i leave the rules for generating the numbers as an excercise for the OP.

Comment: I have updated my question and tried to make it more clear. Thank you for your response.

Comment: you are welcome and it is much clearer,  the rules for appending the matrix would just be geometry...  you know that x^2 + y^2 = r^2 and that x.cos(angle) and y.cos(angle) lay on certain points.  And the regions are defined by the percentages.  ie. 10% is 36 degrees (since the circle is 360 degrees or 2.pi.radians)...  so a function can be constructed for this...

Comment: so the only new trick is % of 360 degrees (or radians if you are using that)...

Comment: You mean to divide the area according to degree in circle ,right?

Comment: exactly (either degrees or radians, whatever you prefer working with)...